# In Typescript, why do equality tests against literal values not narrow the any type?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

In Typescript, testing equality between a variable and a literal will narrow the variable’s type down to the literal type.

```
const value : number = 13
if (value === 42) value // has type 42
```

However, if the value is of type `any`, the type is not narrowed.

```
const value : any = 13
if (value === 42) value // still has type any
```

**Why can’t the test against a literal value narrow the `any` type?**

Narrowing *does* happen if

- `value` is of type `unknown`
- A function with an `is 42` typeguard is explicitly defined and used as the condition
- The test is `typeof` based

The issue happens with Typescript 3.8.3 and can be reproduced [on the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYFcCmBBMBPAXDBHGAXhgAYAoUSWRVNAVTAGswQB3MfFFtzk8hQoBLAGYwAFHXRZsJYqQAsAJgCU8ZDKIB6bTGEQCOADQx2AC2HBz+wzzQAPAA5pgUNABMR4qZsa8OMHklNQ16JlZAmF1bGBUCQ0cXN09vSQMAMRAAJyhsABV2EF96WVV1aUwdPQM45QSYJNd3LzFJPJcQcUrZYJgAcjAUAFsAIzRs-oq-XpjaobGJhqaUrwpRHjdhcFss3IKiiQRsgHN8QmxVc9PY+IBvChgYbLQoFGyg45O+lQoAXyAA).

Comment: if it narrowed the type, then you wouldn't be able to do `if (value === 42) value = 0` because then the definition of the variable would be `value: 42` and thus `0` would be an invalid assignment.

Comment: @VLAZ value is a const so assignment shouldn't be an issue in this case.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes it makes much more sense with the page you linked to. “Primitive” type guards can only “add capabilities”, whereas `any` already has them all, and user-defined guards forcefully set the type.